# Calling local variables from Julia functions (optimize)

Tags: julia, local-variables, function-call

I am dealing with a nested optimization problem in Julia 1.7.3. In particular, I need to optimize a function (say `f1`) that, in turn, depends on the optimization result of another function (say `f2`). Here is a minimal example to illustrate my problem

```
using Optim

function f2(x::Float64, y::Float64) 
    return (x^2 - x - y)^2
end

function f1(y::Float64) 
    x₁ = optimize(x -> f2(x,y), -10, 10).minimizer
    return (y*x₁ - 0.5)^2
end
```

To get the optimizer of `f1`, I do

```
y₁ = optimize(y -> f1(y), -10, 10).minimizer
```

To get the optimizer of `f2`, I do

```
x₁ = optimize(x -> f2(x,y₁), -10, 10).minimizer
```

However, this last step seems very inefficient because it requires an extra optimization call. The optimizer of `f2` is indeed already computed while optimizing `f1` (i.e., `x₁`). Is there a way to retrieve `x₁` without an extra optimization step (e.g., saving `x₁` during the last iteration step of `f1`)?

**Note**: one option is to merge the two optimization problems and simultaneously optimize the objective function with respect to `x` and `y`. However, I cannot follow this approach in the actual application I am dealing with.

Comment: Since the `y` optimize calls the `x` optimize at least once, and especially for the same optimal `y` value, I wouldn't call this **very** inefficient. Just a **maximum** of 2x time. Workarounds have the danger of  delving too much into the black-box of `Optim` solvers and generating more trouble for untested solvers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may store `x₁` in a mutable struct, e.g.

```
using Optim

mutable struct Minimizer{T}
    x::T
    y::T
end

function f2(x::Float64, y::Float64)
    return (x^2 - x - y)^2
end

function f1!(m::Minimizer, y::Float64)
    x₁ = optimize(x -> f2(x,y), -10, 10).minimizer
    m.x = x₁
    return (y*x₁ - 0.5)^2
end

M = Minimizer(NaN, NaN)
M.y = optimize(y -> f1!(M, y), -10, 10).minimizer
@show M
# M = Minimizer{Float64}(1.2971565074975993, 0.3854585027525779)
```